# need ID for ng-repeat elements - for automation testing

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm on a QA automation team and need to be able to select elements created by angular's ng-repeat directive. I can't have the development team code in those ids for me (because of ng-repeat, among other reasons), so how do I get them myself?

code:

```
<tbody>
                <tr class="tblContent" ng-repeat="x in rows | filter:searchFilter | orderBy:'-GUID_Expiry'">
                    <td><input class="btn btn-success myClass3" type="button" value="{{x.ApprovalHyperLink}}" data-link="{{x.ApprovalHyperLink}}" ng-click="testHandler2(x.ApprovalHyperLink)" /></td>
                    <td>{{x.GUID_Expiry}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.PayrollPeriodEndDate | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Client}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.GroupCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.EmployeeFullName}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.EmpEmail}}</td>                        
                    <td>{{x.SSN}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.ApproverFullName}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Approver_Email1}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.GUID}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.DateTimeGenerated | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                </tr>
```

How would I select the ids of the tr elements generated by ng-repeat in this case?

Comment: It seems like you're asking "how can I have ids if I can't have ids." Can you  elaborate any more on what the problem/situation is? As it stands, you have no code and no description of anything about the actual problem, so I don't know how anyone can help. The only thing I could suggest is using `:nth-child` selectors.

Comment: Have you tried using protractor, it does exactly that. You can select via angular expressions.

Comment: `'.tblContent > td:eq(n)'`